# Best way to negate a conditional with double statement, BASH

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements

Good day to all,

I was wondering what is the best way to negate a conditional with two statements:

```
if [ ! "$NUM" -ge 14 -a "$NUM" -le 26 ];then ... fi
or
if [ ! "$NUM" -ge 14 -a ! "$NUM" -le 26 ];then ... fi
or
if ! [ "$NUM" -ge 14 -a "$NUM" -le 26 ];then ... fi
```

What I want to do is that the conditional doesn't do anything when $NUM falls into this close interval: `[14,26]`

Thanks so much in advance for any clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of your options, the superior one is

```
if ! [ "$NUM" -ge 14 -a "$NUM" -le 26 ];then ... fi
```

The advantage of this method over the others is that it works.

Comment: hehe ok, thanks so much, can I ask you a last question? your recommendation also works with double conditional? i.e.: `if ! [ "$NUM" -ge 14 -a "$NUM" -le 26 ] || ! [ "$NUM" -ge 30 -a "$NUM" -le 40 ];then ... fi`  Thanks so much in advance ( :

Comment: If you want to check that it's not in the first interval **and** also not in the second interval, you'd have to use `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: mmm, now I see, Thanks for helping me out ( :